# jquery Как убрать анимацию появления

Tags: jquery

Можно посмотрите на узкой ширине, по нажатию на кнопку меню-плавное появление. Как его убрать, т.е чтобы вообще анимации не было, а просто повлялся контент
https://codepen.io/st-iv/pen/prLyoz?editors=1010

```js
$('#slider .content').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  appendDots: $('#slider .dots'),
  adaptiveHeight: true,
  customPaging : function(slider, i) {
  var title = $(slider.$slides[i]).data('title');
  var thumb = $(slider.$slides[i]).data('thumb');
            
  return '<a class="pager__item"><div class="dot-trumb">'+ title +'<img src="'+thumb+'"></a></div>';
  
},
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu-trigger').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      $list = $($this.attr('data-list'));

    $this.parent().find('.list').not($list).hide(0);
    if ($list.css('display') == 'block') {
      $list.hide();
    } else {
      $list.show();
    }
  }); //end slide toggle

  $(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 500) {
      $('.list').removeAttr('style');
    }
  }); //end resize
}); //end ready
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #F8ECC2;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #65A8A6;
}

.list,
.list li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav a {
  color: #F8ECC2;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px 30px;
}

nav a:hover {
  background: #E65540;
}

.menu-trigger {
  display: none;
  color: #F8ECC2;
}

@media screen and (max-width:500px) {
  .menu-trigger {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .list {
    display: none;
  }
  .list li {
    display: block;
    border-top: 1px #79896D solid;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <a href="#" class="menu-trigger" data-list="#menu">Menu</a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-trigger" data-list="#contacts">Contacts</a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-trigger" data-list="#cities">Cities</a>
  <ul id="menu" class="list">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="contacts" class="list">
    <li><a href="">88003338888</a></li>
    <li><a href="">88003338888</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="cities" class="list">
    <li><a href="">London</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Paris</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Berlin</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: супер. ещё хочу спосить а как при клике на кнопку меню сделать темнее всё содержимое? ( обычно эффект такой в модальных окнах)

Comment: @StepanIvanov это уже другой вопрос. Его лучше задать отдельно